# Arrays in mssql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query that returns several arrays, where each array have 2 positions (0 and 1).
How can i merge this result to a single array, where i dont want the first position (0), only the second position?

```
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);
$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 

//display the results 
for ($i=0;$i<numRows ;$i++) {

$row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<pre>";print_r($row); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: you don't need two loops, you can use a single loop `while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc(`

Comment: You normally to that by changing the database query... .

Comment: @hakre What d i have to change? My query is pretty simple:
$query = "SELECT * FROM Ads";

Comment: You need to change the * into the column you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mssql_query($query);
$data = array();
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
var_dump($data);
```

Getting only the second value would change the `$data =` line to `$data[] = $row[1];`

You may want to use `mssql_fetch_object` instead, or if you are using `mssql_fetch_assoc`, you're probably better off using the associative index instead of the numerical one. Your code is a lot more readable if you use `$row->FieldName` or `$row["FieldName"]` rather than `$row[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you resolve your issue, I would suggest switching to mysqli_fetch_assoc(), as mysql functions are now deprecated.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I have changed to mssql_fetch_object ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the first value then you don't need to merge. I would create a second array like this:

```
while($rows = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
   newArr[] = $rows[1] ;
}
```

That should populate the newArr array with only the second value of your current array.